# subprocess call not executing when if modify the file it uses befor the call

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python program in which first i edit a file and then execute a subprocess call based on the modified file.
The code is

```
mwhome=sys.argv[1]
wlst=mwhome+"/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh"
scriptloc=cwd+"/addldap.py"
dest=cwd+'/t6.py.temp'
source=open(scriptloc,'r')
destination=open('t6.py.temp','w')

for line in source:
    if line.strip().startswith('adminUser'):
        destination.write('adminUser=\"'+adminusername+"\"\n")
        continue
    elif line.strip().startswith('adminPassword'):
        destination.write('adminPassword=\"'+adminpassword+"\"\n")
        continue
    elif line.strip().startswith('adminServerPort'):
        destination.write('adminServerPort=\"'+adminserverport+"\"\n")
        continue
    else:

        destination.write(line)
        continue

shutil.move(dest, scriptloc)


print "starting adding ldap"
output = subprocess.call([ wlst,scriptloc])
```

The subprocess.call is working if i donot execute the modify file for loop and replace.
If i execute the modify for loop the subprocess call is not getting the scriptloc file and just executing the wlst.sh without proper parameters.

Which command is interefering with the execution?

Note:  placed a source.close() and tried but in vain

Comment: You might also try adding destination.close() after the for loop.  Incidentally the calls to "continue" are superfluous.  The if ... elif ... else would only execute one suite and there's an implicit "continue" thereafter.

The subprocess call refers to a name (variable) "wlst" which is not shown in this code; it's not clear whether that might be the problem with your code.  (One wonders why you don't modify addldap.py to accept commands on its stdin and feed the data through a pipe rather than writing through temporary file or refactor addldap as a module to import can call with arguments.

Comment: Removed the continue and added a destination close .
Dunno which one did the trick. Working now.
Thanks

Comment: The continue lines were harmless but superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`destination.close()` is the one that did the trick.  When a file is opened for writing like here, then the various `.write()` are buffered.  It means they may not appear in the real file, or only partly, until the file is either `flush()`-ed or `close()`-ed.